# Each time I put my windows 8 laptop on sleep or Hibernate, i t turns off or restart

Tags: windows-8

I have a problem with my new windows 8 laptop. Each time I put it on sleep or Hibernate, it turns off or restart. And the same thing happens when I close the lid! Why does that happen?? How can I stop it?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the close lid go to Control Panel>Power Options>Change plan settings>Change advance power settings>Power buttons and lid>Lid close action. You can choose action to perform.

Comment: Hello again, after I updated my windows to 8.1 , the same problem came back again and this time when I tried to do your solution, it did not work! :'( Could you please inform me with other solutions if possible? Thank you.